# Object-Array loop

Tags: java, android, loops

android java loop problem
json url = https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
getting sample json url string...
JSON= String json code;

**? itx['name'] not work ?**

```
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                Object[] arr = gson.fromJson(JSON, Object[].class);
                int length = arr.length;
                int i=0;
                System.out.println("itxcc = " + length);
                   for(Object itx : arr) {
                       // Like want.. only itx['name'] field
                       System.out.println("itxcc = " + itx.toString());

                   }
```

log output..
ı like accecs print child only "name" key or anything

```
04-12 13:37:04.398 4030-4069/com.unovasyon.unovasyon I/System.out: itxcc = {id=1.0, name=Leanne Graham, username=Bret, email=Sincere@april.biz, address={street=Kulas Light, suite=Apt. 556, city=Gwenborough, zipcode=92998-3874, geo={lat=-37.3159, lng=81.1496}}, phone=1-770-736-8031 x56442, website=hildegard.org, company={name=Romaguera-Crona, catchPhrase=Multi-layered client-server neural-net, bs=harness real-time e-markets}}
04-12 13:37:04.398 4030-4069/com.unovasyon.unovasyon I/System.out: itxcc = {id=2.0, name=Ervin Howell, username=Antonette, email=Shanna@melissa.tv, address={street=Victor Plains, suite=Suite 879, city=Wisokyburgh, zipcode=90566-7771, geo={lat=-43.9509, lng=-34.4618}}, phone=010-692-6593 x09125, website=anastasia.net, company={name=Deckow-Crist, catchPhrase=Proactive didactic contingency, bs=synergize scalable supply-chains}}
04-12 13:37:04.399 4030-4069/com.unovasyon.unovasyon I/System.out: itxcc = {id=3.0, name=Clementine Bauch, username=Samantha, email=Nathan@yesenia.net, address={street=Douglas Extension, suite=Suite 847, city=McKenziehaven, zipcode=59590-4157, geo={lat=-68.6102, lng=-47.0653}}, phone=1-463-123-4447, website=ramiro.info, company={name=Romaguera-Jacobson, catchPhrase=Face to face bifurcated interface, bs=e-enable strategic applications}}
```

ı am new learning easy example trying... 
Like want.. only itx['name'] field or anythings

Comment: dude whats the question?

Comment: ? itx['name'] not work ?

Comment: If you just want name field then why are you converting it to GSON?

Comment: i don't want to be rude but actually this is funny! this is not a javascript

Comment: ı not know :s  Array[] arr = gson.fromJson(JSON, Array[].class);  ?

Comment: If you are trying to pull them as dynamic then you can use Map

Comment: You need to study java first!!, otherwise you can go with Kotlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: To get the value of a key from `JSONObject`, you need to call the appropriate method on the `JSONObject`

```
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(JSON);
    int length = jsonArray.length();
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("itxcc = " + length);
    for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println("itxcc = " + obj.getString("name"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Edit**
So I am assuming your `JSON` variable contains a valid `json string`, and btw you don't need `GSON`, it is required if you want to map `json` onto your class objects.

Comment: You need to study java!! first otherwise you can go with Kotlin !]

Comment: What do you mean "notting anythnig on log" ?